# About the way nginx deals with listening sockets

Tags: sockets, nginx

It uses mutex to make worker process take turns to accept new connections on each listening socket.

Why not assign specific listening sockets to each worker process ,thus avoiding the overhead of the mutex thing?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely to get a more even distribution of requests over each worker. If you have one port handling more requests than others then the worker handling that socket will have to handle more requests.